# Google Cloud Messaging listening broadcast receiver

Tags: java, php, android, broadcastreceiver

In my android application i am using android push notification everything works fine until the user forces the application close(It happens always nowadays especially with the task monitoring application available in the play store).No more notifications are visible or possible.After some googling i found that From android 3.1, if the user force closes an app, it will stop to be notified of any broadcast until the user does not start your the again.

Is there any solution to prevent the broadcast receiver killing or any other possible (like making a Que of messages that aren't received by the device and send them later)?

Answer (score 1):

> if the user force closes an app, it will stop to be notified of any broadcast until the user does not start your the again.

sorry, that's not true. for sure.

I think you are confusing with something else:  from android 3.x - broadcast receivers would never react to a broadcast until the app is launched for the first time.

if you [implemented properly](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html) your GCM client side - it should work even if user force close the application.   that's because the operating system waking up your application if it has the right broadcast intent filter and receiver, what mean that **your application don't have to be running in order to receive this broadcast.**

> No more notifications are visible or possible

If your indication that the GCM not received is the fact that you don't see any `Notification`, then it's not necessarily true - there is no direct connection between GCM message to the system bar notifications. that's true that usually you'll show notification when push received, but it's deferentially not must.

what I'm saying basically - maybe you have a bug that takes affect after the user force close your app that causing the notifications not to be shown.

Comment: actually i am testing with the sample client delivered with the google cloud messaging api and i am getting the same thing.
What i really want that even if my application is closed(inactive) when i send the message to all the application users a notification appears

Comment: @Hadj Ali Oussama: as I said - there shouldn't be any connection between application state - (running in background/foreground / closed / forced closed) to the fact that you don't receive push notification from google cloud. furthermore - if your application failed from any reason receiving the message (such as when the device was closed, or some error accured) then google automatic retry mechanisem insures you'll receive it when the device become available again

Comment: ok then if there is a google automatic retry mechanism.What you said is true even if i restart my phone and send notification again i get it.I do not get the sent notifications only if i do a force stop to my application.
Thanks.